# If(!empty($_POST)) TRUE all the time?

Tags: php

Despite hours of debugging, searching and reading, I can't figure out why the code below isn't working!? For debugging I have placed `echo '1';`, `echo '2';` and `echo '3';` in the code and I only get 1 on the screen when I run the code. And the most strange thing is that I get 1, both if the fields in the form are empty or not!?

I have followed a video tutorial from PHP Academy on Youtube, and I'm pretty sure I have written exactly the same code as in the video.

[Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JtwX3Ovg6UI)

Preciate some help to be able to continue!

EDIT 1: Have changed bio_name to bio

EDIT 2: Have changed firts_name to first_name

EDIT 3: Added created in SQL query

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
if(isset($_POST['first_name'], $_POST['last_name'], $_POST['bio'])){
    echo '1';
    $first_name = trim($_POST['first_name']);
    $last_name = trim($_POST['last_name']);
    $bio = trim($_POST['bio']);

    if(!empty($first_name) && !empty($last_name) && !empty($bio)){
    echo '2';
    $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO people (firts_name, last_name, bio, created) VALUES (?, ?, ?, NOW())");
    $insert->bind_param('sss', $first_name, $last_name, $bio);

    if($insert->execute()){
        header('Location: index.php');
        echo '3';
        die();
      }
    }   
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST);` and see what you get

Comment: You can also explicitly `var_dump()` the three variables to see what's in there after you assign them. (also - minor typo on your INSERT statement; you have `firts_name` as the column)

Comment: Pretty sure you don't have a field called `bio_name` in your form

Comment: Yes, bio_name was wrong, but I can't run the code to reach echo '3' !?

Comment: With the exception of radio/check boxes (and possibly textareas, though I'd have to look it up) when you POST a form all the fields are sent through to PHPs `$_POST` superglobal (they're all in the HTTP POST) - so even if the an `<input name="first_name" type="text" ... />` field has **no data** in the field the `$_POST['first_name']` index **will** exist (albeit as an empty string) so $_POST **will not** be empty - the only time `$_POST` will be empty is when you first load the page - before submitting the form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're checking `$_POST['bio']` in the first conditional and assigning `$_POST['bio_name']` to `$bio`, which is probably empty and fails the second conditional.

---

Also, your insert query seems wrong - you are listing 3 fields and 4 values to insert. It should have the same number of listed fields and values:

```
 INSERT INTO
     people (first_name, last_name, bio, <LACKING FIELD>)
     VALUES (    ?,          ?,      ?,       NOW()     )
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that, but know I only get a number 2 when I run the code! There must still be some problem if there is no number 3

Comment: Any error output from your insert statement? Maybe `firts_name` typo is the problem? Do you have `firts_name` in your table?

Comment: Seems like I can't spell any thing right! It should be first_name. I have changed in my code, but still not working! I could be as you are writing, but isn't enough with just NOW() !? That's what he is saying in the video!

Comment: @3D-kreativ you have to indicate in which field the value of `NOW()` will be inserted. Maybe advance the video a bit to see if the guy corrects that. `=]`

Comment: Also put some error output after your insert execution. It will be very helpful

Comment: Also the guy from tutorial might have 4 fields in it's table, and skipping the name of the fields. Only this way it will work

Comment: You are right, it must be one more field in the SQL query and now it's working!

Comment: Good to hear that. `=]` Also for future reference, add an `else echo $insert->error;` branch to your `execute()` conditional, it helps finding syntax errors as well as wrong table and field names and other common mistakes.

Comment: I'm glad it's working because I spent so many hours looking for the reason, but I still have one thing I can't get and that is why this code is TRUE all the time? if(isset($_POST['first_name'])) {
echo 'Is set!';
}

Comment: @3D-kreativ `isset` simply checks if the index of the array is set and not `NULL`. That is, as long as your webpage contains an input text field with that name, it will send an empty string (which is not null) for `$_POST['field_name']`. I'd suggest using `if (isset($_POST['field_name']) && $_POST['field_name'] !== '')`. Note that `if (!empty($_POST['field_name']))` also works, but `'0'` is a falsy value and thus considered "empty", so you must account for that in case `0` is a valid value. The docs explain this very well: http://php.net/empty http://php.net/isset

Comment: OK, is this the same as when I'm using if(empty(... and get TRUE all the time despite that the fields in the form are empty, but I recall I have read something about the submit button causing this!?

Comment: @3D-kreativ Not sure if I understood. `empty($var)` will return `true` when `$var == false` (empty string, zero as number or string, empty array and null also equal to false due to lose comparison). Make sure you're giving the correct `name` attributes to your form fields and you should have no problems.

Comment: An `<input type="submit">` with a `name` attribute will have its value submitted alongside with the form data, but it will hardly cause problems.

Comment: Hmmm, I read it in this forum: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?201686-if(!empty(-_POST))-does-not-work-why in the first reply by OctoberWind

Comment: ^ `<input type="image" />` also passes some strange data IIRC.

Comment: @3D-kreativ Yeah, `$_POST` will hardly be empty if you're submitting a form through post (*maybe* if there were no named fields in form, but that doesn't seem very practical).

Comment: What I meant is, forgetting about the submit button and assuming all fields to be empty you'd get `$_POST` to be `array('name' => '', 'password' => '')`. It is not an empty array (it has 2 keys which contain empty string values), hence `empty($_POST)` is always false. Hence, when you submit a form which has named fields through a POST request, the `$_POST` array itself will not be empty.

Comment: @3D-kreativ No problem, you're welcome. `=]` Also, just for the sake of completeness: `if (!empty($_POST))` is normally used to check whether the user is submitting a form/request to the page (to treat such data and display results) or if it is a normal page load. It is useful when you have pages that submit to themselves. Nowadays we tend to use MVC/MVVM/MV* patterns which practically discard that kind of behavior. Of course, it may also be used as a form of preventing direct access to pages that treat form data.